# Simulating StopIteration of Rhino for other JS engine

Tags: javascript, rhino

I wonder how can I simulate `StopIteration` of rhino (and spidermonkey?) in other JS engines (at least those of IE6+ and Chrome). The following conditions must hold true.

```
StopIteration === StopIteration; // true
StopIteration instanceof StopIteration // true
```

*Update 2011-04-05*:

I saw an implementation of [StopIteration](https://github.com/mochi/mochikit/blob/master/MochiKit/Iter.js#L755) in Mochikit, then I checked the [NamedError code](https://github.com/mochi/mochikit/blob/master/MochiKit/Base.js#L1428). I implemented the following code base on the earlier codes. However, the `instanceof` test still failed.

```
NamedError = function (name) {
    this.message = name;
    this.name = name;
};
NamedError.prototype = new Error;
NamedError.prototype.constructor = NamedError;

StpIter = new NamedError("StpIter") // just to see if I can simulate StpIter to be like Mozilla's StopIteration.

print(StpIter === StpIter) // true
print(StpIter instanceof StpIter) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

LOL, I could not believe what I've found. I can just use the JS's `Object`.

```
Object === Object // true
Object instanceof Object // true
```

So, applying in StopIteration

```
var SI = Object// using another object just to test my condition
SI === SI // true
SI instanceof SI // true
```

you may try it on your browser's url bar:
`javascript: SI = Object; alert(SI === SI); alert(SI instanceof SI);`

However, I haven't tested this on Chrome, though I think it will work.

**Update 5/23/2011**

Tested in Chrome and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

...but lots of things are `instanceof Object`.
With your example:

```
 var SI = Object
 undefined
  SI === SI  //true

  SI instanceof SI      //true

  Object instanceof SI     //true

  Error instanceof SI     //true

  new Error() instanceof SI     //true

  TypeError instanceof SI     //true

  new TypeError() instanceof SI     //true
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var SI = function() {};
SI.prototype = Function.prototype;
```

This meets the original two conditions, and fixes two of Scott's examples so they return false (`new Error() instanceof SI` and `new TypeError() instanceof SI`). The other three still return true though. Also `SI instanceof Function` returns true, while `StopIteration instanceof Function` would return false.

If an object could be given a `[[HasInstance]]` internal method (which is required to use it on the right side of `instanceof`), without being a `Function`, then it might be possible to fix these other issues. I don't know any way to do that though.